# After update of AmCharts Area Charts show only part chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, area

I've updated AmCharts from old version to 3.21.12. After that Area charts have only part of chart or no chart at all.

[Old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HrKl.png)
[New version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEzsd.png)

Have anyone an idea where is the problem? There are no errors or warning in console log.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. If that doesn't help, can you post a fiddle of your chart?

Comment: I can not, it's a component made using ExtJS and AmCharts. But I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Problem was in "parseDates" for categoryAxis, before my minPeriod was "mm", when I changed it to "HH" and now it works.

```
categoryAxis: { parseDates: true, minPerion: 'HH', equalSpacing: true}
```